# Auto submit google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a google form which i don't have edit permission (i can only fill this form and submit it). And i want to submit this form on specified time automatically. It possible? If yes, how can i do this.

I have to try createResponse to google form but it work only on form which i have edit permission.

```
function autoSubmitForm() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var formUrl = "form URL";             // URL of the form
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  var items = form.getItems();

  var formResponse = form.createResponse();

  var page1 = items[0];
  var rp_page1 = page1.asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Page 2");
  formResponse.withItemResponse(rp_page1);

  var page2_1 = items[2];
  var rp_page2_1 = page2_1.asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Option 1");
  formResponse.withItemResponse(rp_page2_1);

  var page2_2 = items[3];
  var rp_page2_2 = page2_2.asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse("Option 2");
  formResponse.withItemResponse(rp_page2_2);

  var page2_3 = items[4];
  var options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 4"];
  var rp_page2_3 = page2_3.asCheckboxItem().createResponse(options);
  formResponse.withItemResponse(rp_page2_3);

  var submit = formResponse.submit();
  Logger.log(submit);
  Logger.log(submit.getId());
  Logger.log(submit.getTimestamp());

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(submit.getId());
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2).setValue(submit.getTimestamp());
};
```

Comment: My guess would be that the form owner probably doesn't want you to be able to fill it automatically.  That's why lots of people put catpchas on forms.  But hey I could be wrong.

Comment: **IF**, the Form was open in a browser, there are programs that can fill out a Form and submit it.  It's possible, but not with Apps Script.  There are programs that run from the *browser* that can navigate a Web Page, which is what a Google Form is.  I don't know of any other way that you could automatically submit a Form that you don't have permissions to access, and is not open in the browser.

Comment: @SandyGood IF form open in the _browser_, you know some program to fill and submit this form?

Comment: I don't know how "Up to Date" this program is, or how well it works, but the following link is to a program named AutoIt [Link to AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)